# How to toggle each item as I tab though the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of items with hidden content that shows/hide on hover. I'm trying to get the same functionality to work as I tab through my page. Currently, I can only get every hidden content to appear all at once.

[Here's a live example of my code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwzZWx)

jQuery:

```
$('#top .item .content').hover(function (e) {
    $(this).children('.black-box').stop().slideToggle(300);
});

$('#top').on('keyup', function (e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    var isTabbing = false;

    if (keyCode == 9) {
        if ($('.featured-content').find('*').is(':focus')) {
            if (!isTabbing) {
                isTabbing = true;
                $('.featured-content .item .content .black-box').stop().slideToggle(300);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="top" class="featured-content">
  <div class="item">
      <h3>Tacos</h3>
      <div class="content">
          <img src="http://budapesttimes.hu/wp-content/themes/newsroom14/img/placeholder.png" alt="" class="image" />
          <div class="black-box">
              <div class="background"></div>
              <a href="#">I love tacos!</a>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="start-btn">Start Eating</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
      <h3>Pizza</h3>
      <div class="content">
          <img src="http://budapesttimes.hu/wp-content/themes/newsroom14/img/placeholder.png" alt="" class="image" />
          <div class="black-box">
              <div class="background"></div>
              <a href="#">And Pizzzzzzaaa! P-I-Z-Z-A!</a>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="start-btn">Keep Eating</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
      <h3>OMFG Naps</h3>
      <div class="content">
          <img src="http://budapesttimes.hu/wp-content/themes/newsroom14/img/placeholder.png" alt="" class="image" />
          <div class="black-box">
              <div class="background"></div>
              <a href="#">Because you just ate a ton of food! #foodcoma</a>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="start-btn">Go to sleep</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you explain again what you want to happen when you press 'tab' ?

Comment: When you tab through a site, it goes through all the links, starting with the top and moving it's way down. When I tab to the 1st `.item` I want the `.black-box` to show up. When I tab to the next, I want the 1st box to slide down and the 2nd box to slide up, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to use focus and focus out to trigger your events.

```
$('#top').on('focus', function(){
    // do something
});

$('#top').on('focusout', function(){
    // do something
});
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with tabbing through a site.

Comment: @NOPENOPENOPE pretty sure when you tab through a site your elements get focus then you trigger what you want. Default browser behaviour.

Comment: for example in reference to your comments above. you tab through a link. it gains focus you trigger that black box to come up. when you focus out the black box leaves. no key press trigger is needed.

Comment: when tabbing through a site , actually what you do you trigger the focus event on all links (one by one) or inputs